# Cannot enable Digital Experience

Tags: trailhead, partner-portal, experience-cloud, digital-experience

I have come across a very strange error while trying to enable Digital Experience. I access `Digital Experiences > Settings`, check Enable Digital Experiences and type an available domain name, but I cannot save it. I simply click the `Save` button and nothing happens. Any ideas? I did create a brand new org as per instructions in the Trailhead.

Comment: Do you have pop-up blocker enabled in your browser? If so, can you disable and retry?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug on Salesforce due to a recent update from Chrome (and Edge).

Here is the issue on the trailblazer website : https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002BRMXQA4

Here are workarounds suggested on the previous link :

**Workaround**

1. Impacted users can use an alternate supported browser such as
   Firefox or Safari
2. Chrome 92 users can workaround this issue by adding the following flag to your Google Chrome Shortcut:
   --disable-features="SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs"

We’ve included instructions for how to complete this below. More information on how to make this change can be found here: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwindows

NOTE: This change will not work unless you fully close out of all Chrome Windows and relaunch.

**Windows:**

1. Quit all running instances of Chrome.
2. Right-click your Chrome shortcut.
3. Select Properties.
4. At the end of the Target: line, add the command line flags: --disable-features="SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs"
   With that example flag, it should look like: chrome.exe --disable-features="SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs"
5. Click Apply > OK.
6. Launch Chrome using your shortcut.

**Mac:**

1. Quit all running instances of Chrome.
2. Run the terminal application.
3. In the terminal, run the command:
   /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-features="SuppressDifferentOriginSubframeJSDialogs"
4. Press Enter.